# Using regular expression to comma separate a large number in south asian numbering system

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a regular expression to comma separate a large number based on the [south asian numbering system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system).

A few examples:

- `1,000,000` (Arabic) is `10,00,000` (Indian/Hindu/South Asian)
- `1,000,000,000` (Arabic) is `100,00,00,000` (Indian/H/SA).

The comma pattern repeats for every 7 digits. For example, 
`1,00,00,000,00,00,000`.

From the book Mastering Regular Expressions by Friedl , I have the following regular expression for Arabic numbering system:

```
r'(?<=\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))'
```

For Indian numbering system, I have come up with the following expression but it doesn't work for numbers with more than 8 digits:

```
r'(?<=\d)(?=(((\d{2}){0,2}\d{3})(?=\b)))'
```

Using the above pattern, I get `100000000,00,00,000`.

I am using the Python `re` module (`re.sub()`). Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=\d)(?=(\d{2}){0,2}\d{3}(\d{7})*(?!\d))
```

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> inp = ["1" + "0"*i for i in range(20)]
>>> [re.sub(r"(?<=\d)(?=(\d{2}){0,2}\d{3}(\d{7})*(?!\d))", ",", i) 
     for i in inp]
['1', '10', '100', '1,000', '10,000', '1,00,000', '10,00,000', '1,00,00,000', 
 '10,00,00,000', '100,00,00,000', '1,000,00,00,000', '10,000,00,00,000', 
 '1,00,000,00,00,000', '10,00,000,00,00,000', '1,00,00,000,00,00,000', 
 '10,00,00,000,00,00,000', '100,00,00,000,00,00,000', 
 '1,000,00,00,000,00,00,000', '10,000,00,00,000,00,00,000',
 '1,00,000,00,00,000,00,00,000']
```

As a commented regex:

```
result = re.sub(
    r"""(?x)       # Enable verbose mode (comments)
    (?<=\d)        # Assert that we're not at the start of the number.
    (?=            # Assert that it's possible to match:
     (\d{2}){0,2}  # 0, 2 or 4 digits,
     \d{3}         # followed by 3 digits,
     (\d{7})*      # followed by 0, 7, 14, 21 ... digits,
     (?!\d)        # and no more digits after that.
    )              # End of lookahead assertion.""", 
    ",", subject)
```

Answer (score 7):

I know Tim has answered the question you asked, but assuming you start with numbers rather than strings, have you considered whether you need a regular expression at all? If the machine you are using supported an Indian locale then you could just use the locale module:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "en_IN")
'en_IN'
>>> locale.format("%d", 10000000, grouping=True)
'1,00,00,000'
```

That interpreter session was copied from an Ubuntu system, but be aware that Windows systems may not support a suitable locale (at least mine doesn't), so while this is in some ways a 'cleaner' solution, depending on your environment it may or may not be usable.