# How to Display the Commas in the Indian Numbering System in Python?

Tags: python

Let me know how to display the following format in Python

```
  1234567 => 12,34,567.00
```

I tried with following `"{:,}".format(amt)`
But it displays as `1,234,567.00`

Comment: And that's the correct way of displaying it.

Comment: What format is that? How would you format this number: `12345678`? --> `1,23,45,678.00` ??

Comment: What do you want to do? Filling with two decimals, and after grouping the digits by group if two, except for the first group, where you want three digits together?

Comment: If we copy & past this number in excel sheet. there will be Number Format like above i mentioned. so wants to display same like this

Comment: And what is the cell formatting information in excel?

Comment: So, some googling revealed that you are referring to the [indian numbering system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system). This is vital information that you should add on an international forum!

Comment: yes i want to display it as Indian Rupee Format

Comment: This should solve your problems: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14238258/4177384
To get your exact formatting requirements use `"%.2f"` instead of `"%d"`

Comment: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "en_IN")
        inr_amt_format = locale.format("%.2f", amt, grouping=True)
        return inr_amt_format

Comment: Thanks. above works finely