# Converting a full column of integer into string with thousands separated using comma in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Say I have population data stored in a column of a dataframe using pandas in python with Country names as row indices. How do I convert the whole column of numbers into string thousands separator using commas. 
Basically, I need 12345678,integer, converted into 12,345,678.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `apply` to format the numbers.

```
In [40]: ps.apply('{:,}'.format)
Out[40]:
CountryA    12,345,678
CountryB     3,242,342
dtype: object

In [41]: ps
Out[41]:
CountryA    12345678
CountryB     3242342
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Is this possible --> `778123232232` --> `77,81,23,323,232` ?

Comment: You could do that by `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "en_IN")` See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14238258

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi where did u get that data from

Comment: That's the default - https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language - Using the comma as a thousands separator - `'{:,}'.format(1234567890) == '1,234,567,890'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex as well.

```
df['Population'].str.replace(r"(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)", ",")
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cVYAGw/1

Comment: Note: You'd have to convert type if Population is in any other type. `df['Population'].astype(str).str.replace..`