# Data format and pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, format

I am using Pandas to format things nicely in a tabular format

```
data = []
for i in range (start, end_value):
    data([i, value])
    # modify value in some way

print pd.DataFrame(data)
```

gives me

```
      0             1
0    38  2.500000e+05
1    39  2.700000e+05
2    40  2.916000e+05
3    41  3.149280e+05
```

**How can I modify this to remove scientific notation and for extra points add thousands separator?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data['column_name'] = data['column_name'].apply('{0:,.2f}'.format)
```

thanks to [John Galt's previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41314785/1870832)